# base64-Encoding breaks smime-encrypted emaildata

Tags: perl, smime

I'm using Mime::Lite to create and send E-Mails. Now I need to add support for S/Mime-encryption and finally could encrypt my E-Mail (the only Perllib I could install seems broken, so I'm using a systemcall and openssl smime), but when I try to create a mime-object with it, the E-Mail will be broken as soon as I set the Content-Transfer-Encoding to base64. To make it even more curious, it happens only if I set it via `$myMessage->attr`. If I'm using the constructor ->new everything is fine, besides a little warning which I suppress by using `MIME::Lite->quiet(1);`

Is it a bug or my fault? Here are the two ways how I create the mime-object.

1. Setting the Content-Transfer-Encoding via construtor and suppress the warning:

   ```
   MIME::Lite->quiet(1); 
   my $msgEncr = MIME::Lite->new(From   =>'me@myhost.com',
                           To     => 'you@yourhost.com',
                          Subject => 'SMIME Test',
                          Data    => $myEncryptedMessage,
                          'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'base64');

   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition'        =>  'attachment');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition.filename'   =>  'smime.p7m');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.smime-type' => 'enveloped-data');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.name' => 'smime.p7m');

   $msgEncr->send;             

   MIME::Lite->quiet(0);
   ```
2. Setting the Content-Transfer-Encoding via `$myMessage->attr` which breaks the encrypted Data, but won't cause a warning:

   ```
   my $msgEncr = MIME::Lite->new(From  => 'me@myhost.com',
                          To         => 'you@yourhost.com',
                          Subject    => 'SMIME Test',
                          Data => $myEncryptedMessage);

   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition'        =>  'attachment');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition.filename'       =>  'smime.p7m');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.smime-type' => 'enveloped-data');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.name' => 'smime.p7m');
   $msgEncr->attr('Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'base64');

   $msgEncr->send;
   ```

I just don't get why my message is broken when I'm using the attribute-setter. Thanks in advance for your help!

Besides that i'm unable to attach any file to this E-Mail without breaking the encrypted message again.

Comment: You need to bump them over another 4 spaces after a list item for markdown to tell that you mean them as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in one comment the difference in setting the encoding in the construtor of the mimeobject or with the `->attr`-Setter is, that the construtor just sets the encoding in the mimeheader. By using the `->attr`-Setter mime encodes the data with base64.

So in my case, my previously generated mimeobject - which is base64-encoded and with s/mime encrypted - read from a file **needs** to set the encoding in the construtor (and suppress the warning) so no more encoding will be done by mime. Otherwise mime will encode the data **again** and therefore break the encryption and the email itself.

I finally got attachments to work. To achieve this I create a normal multipart/mixed mimeobject, print this object into a normal file, encrypt this file with openssl smime, read this whole file (except the 6 headerlines) into a variable and use this as the datainput. Additionally I set the Content-Transfer-Encoding to base64 using the construtor (so no encoding is done to my data).

I hope this will help someone else then me ;)

Comment: I found this little piece of information on MIME:Lite in http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.028/lib/MIME/Lite.pm 

WAIT! 

MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this
Make a script call showmail.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<STDIN>) { print $_; }
```

Test it like

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;
use MIME::Base64;
$myEncryptedMessage = encode_base64("This is not valid encrypted message\n");
MIME::Lite->send('sendmail', "./showmail.pl"); ## Add this for debugging.
MIME::Lite->quiet(1); my $msgEncr = MIME::Lite->new(From   =>'me@localhost',
                 To     => 'you@localhost',
                 Subject => 'SMIME Test',
                 Data    => $myEncryptedMessage,
                 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'base64');
$msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition'        =>  'attachment');
$msgEncr->attr('Content-Disposition.filename'   =>  'smime.p7m');
$msgEncr->attr('Content-Type' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime');
$msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.smime-type' => 'enveloped-data');
$msgEncr->attr('Content-Type.name' => 'smime.p7m');
$msgEncr->send();
```

you should see something like.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"; smime-type="enveloped-data"
X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.028 (F2.74; B3.07; Q3.07)
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2012 10:40:51 -0400
From: me@localhost
To: you@localhost
Subject: SMIME Test
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBub3QgdmFsaWQgZW5jcnlwdGVkIG1lc3NhZ2UK
```

The message is encoded base64, but the real message still needs to be correctly
encypted. You need to make sure that is the case since $myEncryptedMessage is
passed in. With the debug output, you can compare with a known good encrypted mail
and see if the headers are good, as far as I can see the headers are fine, it is probably
the data that is not valid.

Comment: The problem with the base64-encoding is, that mimelite seems to encode the given object if you set the Content-Transfer-Encoding via `$myObject->attr()`. So I encode a message, encrypt it via systemcall and rebuild a (new) mimeobject based on that data. If I set the Content-Transfer-Encoding on this object the data should NOT be encoded **again**. I guess I will revisit my question to clarify it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, my test shows $myEncryptedMessage is passed verbatim to the body regardless of the attr set. You might want to do some tests and see what it actually does to the message.

Comment: It's passed verbatim, because you set the Content-Transfer-Encoding via the construtor of the mimeobject. therefore no encoding is done, but this raises a warning. That's why I'm using the `->quiet(1)` to suppress this warning. So I am wondering why it will throw a warning, but work different as if I set it seperatly via `->attr`.

Comment: you are correct on that, I also checked Lite.pm's implementation of base64 is correct, I suspect the data itself isn't right. Are you able to verify that?

Comment: At the moment I create the emails while suppressing this warning, so that my data is not encoded again and my client can decrypt the email correctly, because the data wasn't changed by mimelite. I need to extend my testscript to be able to add attachements too, and therefore the Transfer-Encoding may need to be set via `->attr` du to multipart/mixed. I'm not quiet sure if I'm just very consufed by all this "try and error"-stuff or if it's just as complicated to send smime-encrypted emails (with attachements) out of perl (encryption via systemcall).

Comment: I posted the explanation of my problem as a new answer and accepted it, but I'll give you the bounty as a thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this with a real mail client, but this is what I think may work for multi-parts.

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;
use MIME::Base64;
MIME::Lite->send('sendmail', "./showmail.pl"); ## <---- for testing only
my $from_address = "nobody@localhost";
my $to_address = "somebody@localhost";
my $mail_host = "localhost";
my $subject = "Subject list";
my $message_body = "Attachment list";
my @files = ("crypt.data1","crypt.data2");
$msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $from_address,
  To => $to_address,
  Subject => $subject,
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

foreach $c(@files) {
   $msg->attach (
     Disposition => 'attachment',
     Type => "application/x-pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; smime-type=enveloped-data",
     Path => $c,
   ) or die "Error adding $c: $!\n";
}
$msg->send;
```

Comment: I added some information to my answer how I solved the attachment-problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace $myEncryptedMessage with encode_base64($myEncryptedMessage)

and use MIME::Base64;

Comment: The encrypted data is still broken if I use this method.